# Reprint PDF document to PDF printer - generally and Delphi specific

Tags: delphi, pdf, printing, pdf-generation

My system produces PDF document that by some unknown reason is quite large - over 1 MB. If I print this PDF document with PDF printer (Bullzip, PDF Architect, ect.) to another PDF file then resulting PDF file is only 40kb is size and that is fine.

So - the question is - how to reprint PDF file with PDF printer to antoher file. I would like to have PDF-printer-agnostic solution and let user to choose what PDF printer to install and use.

I am seeking Embarcadero Delphi solution, but I would be happy to receive the general answers as well (I can adapte them to myself for Delphi implementation).

Usually each processing system (MS office Word or Excel, ReportBuilder) support opening specific files and printing them silently. But onviously PDF files can be opened by different systems and printed as well. Is the common denominator? Or maybe I should stick to some specific PDF system and add additional requirement on users.

Additional details:
I am using Digital Metaphors ReportBuilder and Pragnaan ReportBuilder Export Device http://www.rarefind.com/rbpro/index.html. Pragnaan takes ppReport - TReport component and FileName - TmpFileName, the code is one line:

```
ExportToPDF(ppReport, TmpFileName);
```

We are using Pragnaan because it gently handles diacritics in non-English languages, but it has this drawback of making huge files. We are sticking with Pragnaan, because there is nothing better, but we just need reprinting already complete PDF file.

Comment: Hard to follow the question here. Sounds like the issue relates to your code that generates pdf. We can't see it. So how can we help you with it?

Comment: I added additional details and full source code, unfortuntely it is only one line long. Hope, it helps.

Comment: What response did you get from the vendor of this component when you asked them for support?

Comment: You might try running one of your files past PDFtk - https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/ - see the -compress option.  I've used its -flatten to replace fields in a PDF form  with the user-inputted text of them.

Comment: Component vendor has this message: "There is no technical support available for this product. Limited information and/or source code may be available on our website. Kindly evaluate the product fully before making a purchase. The product is sold in an 'as-is' condition and with a no refund policy."

Comment: Time to find a different vendor in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFForge/PDFCreator COM interface allows to reprint silently PDF file in almost optimally smaller size and preserving all the formatting and diacritics.

```
    Queue: IQueue;
    Job: IPrintJob;
    PDFCreator: IPDFCreator;
begin  
    PDFCreator:=CoPdfCreatorObj.Create;
    PDFCreator.AddFileToQueue(AFileName);

    Queue:=CoQueue.Create;
    Queue.Initialize;
    Job:=Queue.NextJob;
    Job.SetProfileByGuid('DefaultGuid');
    Job.SetProfileSetting('OpenViewer', 'False');
    Job.SetProfileSetting('OpenWithPdfArchitect', 'False');
    Job.SetProfileSetting('ShowProgress', 'False');
    Job.SetProfileSetting('ShowQuickActions', 'False');
    //SkipPrintDialog is mentioned in the documentation
    //http://docs.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator/latest/en/pdfcreator/com-interface/reference/settings/
    //but might no be available in free versions of PDFForge/Create, that is why we don't even attempt to use it.
    //Job.SetProfileSetting('SkipPrintDialog', 'True');
    Job.ConvertTo(ANewFileName);

    Queue.ReleaseCom;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The PDF file isn't compressed. 
"Saving as" from Acrobat Reader or Foxit Reader will compress it.

You can also use QPDF or a similar application in command line.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/qpdf/files/qpdf/7.0.0/

Answer (score 1):

I hesitate to post a reference to a 3rd party library as an answer to your q, but in addition to PDFtk, if you are using ReportBuilder, I suggest you take a look at TExtraDevices at http://www.waler.com/products.htm.

This library presents as a Delphi component which you place on the same form as you ReportBuilder components and adds the option to output the report to a number of additional formats including PDF.  I used it in the D5/7 era and it "just worked" so far as PDF reports was concerned:  I never had any problem with the size of the generated PDF reports, which were mostly a few Kb but ymmv.

It's not free ($50) and hasn't been updated recently, largely I imagine because there would be no reason for it to be - at least it has been updated since Delphi 2009, so is available "on the right side" of the Ascii/Unicode divide.

If TExtraDevices does what you want, it would avoid the need for any post-processing of your report files.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find partial solution. I can print PDF document (large) to PDF document (small) with COM automation of Bullzip printer:

```
var BZUtil, BZSettings: OleVariant;
    TmpPrinterName, TmpString: String;
begin
  BZUtil:=CreateOleObject('Bullzip.PdfUtil');
  BZSettings:=CreateOleObject('Bullzip.PdfSettings');

  TmpPrinterName:=BZUtil.DefaultPrinterName;
  BZSettings.SetValue('Output', 'C:\TMP\reprinted_file.pdf');

  BZSettings.SetValue('ShowSettings', 'never');
  BZSettings.SetValue('ShowSaveAS', 'never');
  BZSettings.SetValue('ShowPDF', 'no');
  BZSettings.SetValue('ShowProgress', 'no');
  BZSettings.SetValue('ShowProgressFinished', 'no');
  BZSettings.SetValue('ConfirmOverwrite', 'no');

  BZSettings.SetValue('AfterPrintProgramMode', 'hide');
  BZSettings.SetValue('RunOnSuccessMode', 'hide');
  BZSettings.SetValue('RunOnErrorMode', 'hide');

  //No programs are specified
  //TmpString:=BZSettings.GetValue('RunOnError');
  //MessageDlg('RunOnError: '+TmpString, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
  //TmpString:=BZSettings.GetValue('RunOnSuccess');
  //MessageDlg('RunOnSuccess: '+TmpString, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
  //TmpString:=BZSettings.GetValue('AfterPrintProgram');
  //MessageDlg('AfterPrintProgram: '+TmpString, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
  BZSettings.WriteSettings(True);
  try
    BZUtil.PrintFile('C:\TMP\original_file.pdf', TmpPrinterName);
  except
    on E: Exception do begin
      MessageDlg(E.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  MessageDlg('All is OK', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
```

But there is one serious problem with this solution - PrintFile procedure opens new PDF file for a moment and then closes it but the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC home screen remains opened. Automatically opened Acrobat home screen (welcome message, recent file list etc.) is very annoying issue which has not solution generally, e.g. Windows registry changes https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1812870 do not solve issue in this case. I am sure that Bullzip PrintFile is the cause of the problem - it somehow ignores the settings that required silent print.

So - now there is only one open problem - how to deal with opening/closing of Acrobat Reader during Bullzip silent print. I made the bug request to Bullzip company but it can take time to process my issue. Maybe some workaround exist?

Comment: " how to deal with opening/closing ..." You should post that as a new question, SO has no mechanism for answering a question raised in an answer.  Did you try PDFtk, btw?

Comment: I had a look now on PDFtk - it has a free version, there are big chances that I will try it after some time when I will be back to this project. Thanks.

Comment: did you read the manual or you want to stick with this reprint hack?  
Type: TPDFCompressionMethod
Default: cmMaxCompress
TPDFCompressionMethod = (cmFastest,
cmNormal, cmMaxCompress);
Specifies the type of compression to be used to
compress text and Image.
Indicate the type of compression to be used to
compress text and Image. CompressionMethod
will be used only if UseCompression = True.
Compressing will help in reducing file size.
Images are compressed only when
ExportImageFormat=ifBMP. Note: In order to use compression, enable the
ZLib option in PsRBDefines.inc located in blabla

Comment: My TPsRBExportPDF component already had properties that enabled the maximum compression rate by default. I checked and had experiments once more, I recompiled component source code with additional checks to observe that ZLib compression is used indeed, but no improvement.